# Título interativo em uma Modal

Tags: php, html

Bom, eu tenho esse html:

```
<div>
    <span class="upgrade_description"> Upgrade 1 Segunda a Sexta das 20h às 02h</span> <a href="#abrirModal" rel="modal" class="button">R$ 399</a>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="upgrade_description"> Upgrade 2 Sábados das 08h às 20h </span><a href="#abrirModal" rel="modal" class="button">R$ 299</a>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="upgrade_description">Upgrade 3 Sábados das 08h às 14h - 14h às 20h </span><a href="#abrirModal" rel="modal" class="button">R$ 199</a>
</div>
<div>
    <span> Upgrade 4 Domingo das 08h às 14h - 14h às 20h </span><a href="" rel="modal" class="button">R$ 199</a>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="upgrade_description"> Upgrade 5 Sábados das 20h às 2h  </span><a href="#abrirModal" rel="modal" class="button">R$ 199</a>
</div>
```

Ele faz a listagem de alguns serviços(upgrade 1, upgrade 2, etc) e traz em cada um deles um botão que abre uma modal contendo um formulário.
O formulário é o mesmo para qualquer um deles, portanto vou utilizar a mesma modal.

Porém, quero que o título (H1) da modal seja de acordo com o serviço selecionado.

Por exemplo: se o usuário clicar para abrir a modal do upgrade 1, o título será **Upgrade 1**, já se clicar no botão do upgrade 2 o título será **Upgrade 2**, e assim por diante.

Alguém tem uma sugestão de como posso fazer isso?

**A modal**

CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
overflow:scroll; /* activa scroll da página se a modal for muito comprida */
}

.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
width: 600px;
position: relative;
margin: 5% auto;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;


-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
}

 .close {
background: #00B92F;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #2AFF2A; }
```

HTML(cabeçalho, que vai receber o title):

```
<div id="abrirModal" class="modalDialog">
    <a class="close" title="Fechar" href="#fecharModal">X</a>
    <div class="modal">
    <span class="title_modal"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o código do modal? é do jQuery? nesse caso podes setar o `title` como option.

Comment: @Sergio A modal é gerada apenas com Css, vou adicionar a pergunta o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de fazer isso com JavaScript...

```
var upgrades = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
var modal = document.querySelector('#abrirModal .title_modal');
for (var i = 0; i<upgrades.length; i++){
 upgrades[i].addEventListener('click', mudarTitulo);   
}

function mudarTitulo(){
    modal.innerHTML = this.parentNode.querySelector('span').innerHTML;
}
```

Este código escuta cliques em cada link e vai substituir o titulo que a modal mostra. Cada vez que um clique é detetado ele procura a `div` pai desse `a` e depois o `span` que suponho ser a descrição que queres usar.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvof8kkc/

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!